# Doesn´t get right information from wp_Query in wordpress using Easy Content Types

Tags: wordpress

Have problems to sort out right information using WP_Query together with Easy Content Types.
My query looks like this

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'buildarea',  'territory' => 'centrum' ));
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php echo the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; 
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

territory is a taxonomy and i want to sort out items belong to "centrum" and to the post-type "buildarea". I also have a post-type called "combuilding" using sam taxonomy. When I use the query i got result from both "combuilding" and "buildarea". What have I done wrong?

Regards Mats Gustavsson

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'buildarea',  'territory' => 'centrum' ));


wp_reset_query();
```

`wp_reset_query()` restores the $wp_query and global post data to the original main query

Here is the reference manual [wp_reset_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

Comment: always have wp_reset_query() when the query is done, tested to set it before, didn´t help